# Can delegate classes ignore the "this" object passed in get/set if it is already initialized via a constructor

Tags: kotlin

I came across this [snippet of code on Github](https://gist.github.com/Zhuinden/ea3189198938bd16c03db628e084a4fa#file-fragmentviewbindingdelegate-kt-L43).

Notice how the "this" object is already initialized via the constructor, yet when resolving the delegation, the passed in "this" object is used instead.

```
class FragmentViewBindingDelegate<T : ViewBinding>(
    val fragment: Fragment, // <<< "this" object is passed upon initialization
    val viewBindingFactory: (View) -> T
) : ReadOnlyProperty<Fragment, T> {

    // ...

    override fun getValue(thisRef: Fragment, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        return viewBindingFactory(thisRef.requireView()).also { this.binding = it }
        // ^^^ Same object. Can fragment.requireView() be used instead of thisRef.requireView()?
    }
}
```

When both "this" object are the same, is it required to use the "this" object passed via get/setValue()? Can I use the "this" object passed in the constructor instead?

Comment: Since they are the same reference to object, it might be possible to use them interchangeably.

Comment: Yes, it can be used interchangeably. On KotlinConf 2019 Chet Haase has raised the same question: https://youtu.be/MYQWtNG2so8?t=1096 
Looks like it puzzles many people)

Answer (score 0):

They don't have to be the same. The `val fragment: Fragment` instance passed for the constructor can be any Fragment, while the `thisRef: Fragment` passed to the `getValue` function will be the instance holding the property.

I don't know android, so I don't understand the purpose of this class. If those instances are supposed to be the same, you should be able to use them interchangeably. Otherwise you should clarify this question with the authors of the class. Maybe ask them to add documentation.